# Validating ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have an `ItemsControl`, which visually represents a list of models. Each model consists of two values represented by `ComboBox`es. My requirement is that all of these `ComboBoxe`s have selected value.

The window has an OK button, which is enabled only if all elements on the window are validated:

```
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="100" Margin="4" Height="24" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Content="OK">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                                    
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbBeneficiaries, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbName, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbHomeNumber, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbStreetNumber, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbStreet, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                ...
```

How can I validate contents of the `ItemsControl` in such way, that I'll be able to add it to my set of conditions for the OK button?

Comment: You can write a `Convertor` which will take items collection of `ItemController` as input and iterate over each item to validate the required condition.